# Error when Display Data Arrays to JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I want to display:

```
double c[][][]=new double[1][9][2];
double a[][][]=new double[1][9][2];
```

to JTable.
I used this code:

```
int row=4,column=9;
    String isi[][] = new String[4][9];
    String isi2[][] = new String[1][20];
    TableModel premise = new DefaultTableModel(row, column);
            for(row=0;row<4;row++){
                for(column=0;column<9;column++) {
                    if(row<2) {
                     isi[row][column]= String.valueOf(c[0][column][row]);
                     premise.setValueAt(isi[row][column], row, column);
                    }
                    else {
                     row = row - 2;
                     isi[row][column] = String.valueOf(a[0][column][row]);
                     premise.setValueAt(isi[row][column], row, column);
                    }
                }     
            }
            j_premise.setModel(premise);
    row=1; column=20;
    TableModel cons = new DefaultTableModel(row, column);
             for(row=0;row<1;row++){
                for(column=0;column<20;column++) {
                     isi2[row][column] = Double.toString(T[column][row]);
                     cons.setValueAt(isi2[row][column], row, column);
                }
             }
             j_consequent.setModel(cons);
```

but suddenly my personal computer wasn't responding after compiled it.
How to fix this?

Comment: Your code is in an infinite loop: `for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) { if (row < 2) { ... } else { row = row - 2; ... } }` this causes `row` to reset to `0` as soon as it reaches `2`...

Comment: So I've to separate between c and a?

Comment: Why do you use single element array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for(row=0;row<4;row++){
   for(column=0;column<9;column++) {
      if(row<2) {
         isi[row][column]= String.valueOf(c[0][column][row]);
         premise.setValueAt(isi[row][column], row, column);
      }
      else {
         int row2 = row - 2;
         isi[row2][column] = String.valueOf(a[0][column][row2]);
         premise.setValueAt(isi[row2][column], row2, column);
      }
   }     
}
```